# Unable to access to AngularJS's variables after having set them

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working in a project and I am having some problems to work with some variables in the controller. This is the controller's code

```
angular.module('wc-general-informe-notas')
.controller('AnalisisEvaluacionController', ['$scope','$state','urlBasePartials', 'idColegio', 'anio', 'EvaluacionFactory',
function ($scope, $state, urlBasePartials, idColegio, anio, EvaluacionFactory) {
    //Default ranges that clasifies 
    $scope.scoreRange = [
        {level: "Very low", from: 1, to: 3.9},
        {level: "Low", from: 4, to: 4.9},
        {level: "High", from: 5, to: 5.9},
        {level: "Excellent", from: 6, to: 7},
    ];
    $scope.setRange = function () {
        $scope.ranges = $scope.scoreRange;
    }
    $scope.informe =13;
    $scope.levels = [];
    $scope.idColegio = idColegio;
    $scope.anio = anio;
    $scope.nombreCurso = $('#curso option:selected').text();
    $scope.casillero = $('#casillero option:selected').text();
    $scope.evaluation = null;
    $scope.setRange();

    $scope.generateReport = function () {
        EvaluacionFactory.patch({
            idEvaluacion: $scope.filtroCasillero,
            idSector: $scope.filtroAsignatura,
            idCurso: $scope.filtroCurso,
            idEvaluacionCursoSector: $scope.evaluacionCs[$scope.filtroPeriodo],
            'expand[]': ['r_evaluacion_nota','nota_detalle','r_nota_alumno','alumno_detalle']
        }, function (evaluation) {
            $scope.evaluation = evaluation;
            $scope.adjustLevels();
        })
    }
    $scope.getRange = function (value) {
        for (var i in $scope.ranges)
        {
            var range = $scope.ranges[i];
            if (value == range.from || value == range.to || (value > range.from && value < range.to))
                return range.level;
        }
    }
    function init() {
        $scope.profesor = null;
        $scope.$parent.cursos_lista.forEach(function (curso) {
            if(curso.id == $scope.filtroCurso)
            {
                if(curso.profesor != undefined)
                {
                    var profesor = curso.profesor.usuario_detalle[0];
                    $scope.profesor = profesor.nombres + " " + profesor.apellido_paterno + " " + profesor.apellido_materno;
                    $scope.profesor = $scope.profesor.toString().toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        })
        if ($scope.ranges == undefined)
            $scope.setRange();
        if ($scope.filtroCasillero != null)
            $scope.generateReport();
    }
    init();
    $scope.adjustLevels = function () {
        for(var i in $scope.evaluation.scores)
            $scope.levels[$scope.evaluation.scores[i].id] = $scope.getRange($scope.evaluation.scores[i].valor);
    }
}]);
```

What this controller does is get data from a factory which brings all the scores that an evaluation has. I render all the data correctly in the view, the problem is that in the view the user can modify `$scope.ranges` and then click a button (`ng-click`) that calls `$scope.adjustLevels` which should show the new level according to the new `$scope.ranges`' values.

Every time `$scope.adjustLevels` is called throws an error which  said that
`$scope.evaluation` is `null`, even though there is no problem when is called after receiving the data from the factory.

It seems that I can't access all those variables I have set previously. 
What can be happening? I hadn't had this sort of problems before.
I have tried adding `console.log($scope.levels)` and `console.log($scope.evaluation)` and it shows their content only when the method `init()` is called but not when I called it from the button I have in the view. When I do that is shows an empty array and `null` which are the values defined by default at the beginning

Comment: Can you please share the html code so that we can have look how it is being binded?

Answer (score 0):

You expect that the `$scope.generateReport()` will set the `$scope.evaluation` but then you have this condition

```
if ($scope.filtroCasillero != null)
        $scope.generateReport();
```

The `$scope.filtroCasillero` is not declared which makes the `$scope.generateReport()` never to be run and thats why the `$scope.evaluation` is null

Comment: filtroCasillero is defined in the view. It's an ng-model. If I don't have that condition the factory fails because that variable is required for that factory to work. That's the reason

Comment: @Jorge the init will run before the view is rendered and therefore the value will always be null. To get around this you could call the init from the view instead by setting ng-init=”init()” on the tag the ng-controller is defined

Comment: I have removed the two last ifs and added 
if ($scope.$parent.filtroCasillero == null ) return; at the beginning of the method generateReport. What can I do to access to $scope.evaluacion after being set in generateReport?.
I tried with ng-init="init()" but didn't worl

Comment: I could solve the problem with $scope.evaluation adding a new global variable which stores the value given by the factory. In this way I can access it afterwards. But now when I update the model $scope.niveles it doesn't update the view

Comment: @Jorge strange. A start would be to define a initial value to all the NgModels in the controller $scope. Also, add a console.log and check that the EvaluacionFactory.patch really returns something

Comment: It does return I have checked the network. I had set all the ngModels to null or as an empty array but then it shows null without the returned value and this happens only for $scope.evaluation which is the one I need to work with, all the rest work fine. Now I am struggling to see why it doesn't update the view when I modify the ngModel  level

Comment: @Jorge Ok, great. Then the problem might be on how you execute the callback in EvaluacionFactory.patch(). Could you please show that?